# Changing database at runtime with MVC WebApi 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I want to change the connection to a database at runtime in a REST Api. I want to put a variable of the request and let the Api decide which connectionstring to use.

For example:
I put the variable "dbid" with the value "develop"  in the request header and send it to the Api.

The Api sees the header and gets the correct connectionstring from the web.config.

I have three layers (data, business, api). The data contains EntityFramework to get and set data. Like this:

```
public class WebsiteContext : IocDbContext, IWebsites
{
    public DbSet<Website> Websites { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Website> GetAll()
    {
        return Websites.ToList();
    }
}
```

(IoCDbContext.cs)

```
public class IocDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public IocDbContext() : base("develop")
    {
    }

    public void ChangeDatabase(string connectionString)
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString= connectionString;
    }
}
```

In the business I have a class to retrieve data from the datalayer and do some logical stuff (not needed here, but still good for the story).

```
public class Websites : IWebsites
{
    private readonly Data.Interfaces.IWebsites _websiteContext;

    #region Constructor

    public Websites(Data.Interfaces.IWebsites websiteContext)
    {
        _websiteContext = websiteContext;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IWebsites implementation


    public IEnumerable<Website> GetWebsites()
    {
        List<Data.Objects.Website> websiteDtos = _websiteContext.GetAll().ToList();

        return websiteDtos.Select(web => web.ToModel()).ToList();
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class WebsiteMapper
{
    public static Website ToModel(this Data.Objects.Website value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new Website
        {
            Id = value.Id,
            Name = value.Name
        };
    }
}
```

And, last but not least, the controller:

```
public class WebsiteController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IWebsites _websites;

    public WebsiteController(IWebsites websites)
    {
        _websites = websites;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Website> GetAll()
    {
        return _websites.GetWebsites().ToList();
    }
}
```

My Unity configuration:

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<Business.Interfaces.IWebsites, Websites>();

        container.RegisterType<IDbContext, IocDbContext>();
        container.RegisterType<IWebsites, WebsiteContext>();

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

So as you can see the connection string with the name "develop" is used by default. This will return a website with the name "website". Now I would change the header variable "dbid" to "live". The api should see this and should get the connectionstring that corresponds with the name "live". This last part is something I am trying, but nothing works.

This I tried:

- Adding session to webapi. This means I break the stateless idea of REST api: not done
- Statics cannot work either, because everyone could get the same connectionstring, but its user specific
- Google, but most of the examples don't work for me
- Searching StackOverflow... See previous point.

This is driving me crazy! There should be a way to change the connectionstring given by a value in a request header, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same scenario in a multi-tenant application I created where I use a different connection string for each tenant.

It doesn't matter the implementation you choose, but you have to determine how you are going to differentiate each request per connection string.  In my application, I created a custom route value, and used it in the url to differentiate each request.  The important thing is to create whatever this mechanism is, and it needs to be the 1st thing you register in your DI framework, on a per request basis.

For example (using Ninject):

```
private static void RegisterServicdes(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ISiteContext>().To<SiteContext>().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<IDbContextFactory>().To<DbContextFactory>().InRequestScope();
    // register other services...
}
```

Rather than your implementation of your DbContext, I would change to be this, then always create your DbContext instance via a DbContextFactory.

```
public class IocDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public IocDbContext(string connectionStringType) : base(connectionStringType) { }
}
```

Then you need to create a DbContextFactory that you use when you create your DbContext, and take the above class as a dependency.  Or you can take the dependency into your services, and pass it into the DbContextFactory instead.

```
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    TestModel CreateContext();
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    private string _siteType;
    public DbContextFactory(ISiteContext siteContext)
    {
        _siteType = siteContext.Tenant;
    }

    public TestModel CreateContext()
    {
        return new TestModel(FormatConnectionStringBySiteType(_siteType));
    }

    // or you can use this if you pass the IMultiTenantHelper dependency into your service
    public static TestModel CreateContext(string siteName)
    {
        return new TestModel(FormatConnectionStringBySiteType(siteName));
    }

    private static string FormatConnectionStringBySiteType(string siteType)
    {
        // format from web.config
        string newConnectionString = @"data source={0};initial catalog={1};integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";

        if (siteType.Equals("a"))
        {
            return String.Format(newConnectionString, @"(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB", "DbOne");
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format(newConnectionString, @"(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB", "DbTwo");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so when accessing your DbContext:

```
public class DbAccess
{
    private IDbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;
    public DbAccess(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        using (IocDbContext db = _dbContextFactory.CreateContext())
        {
            // use EF here...
        }
    }   
}
```

ISiteContext interface implementation (for using route).

```
public interface ISiteContext
{
    string Tenant { get; }
}

public class SiteContext : ISiteContext
{
    private const string _routeId = "tenantId";

    private string _tenant;
    public string Tenant {  get { return _tenant; } }

    public SiteContext()
    {
        _tenant = GetTenantViaRoute();
    }

    private string GetTenantViaRoute()
    {
        var routedata = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

        // Default Routing
        if (routedata.Values[_routeId] != null)
        {
            return routedata.Values[_routeId].ToString().ToLower();
        }

        // Attribute Routing
        if (routedata.Values.ContainsKey("MS_SubRoutes"))
        {
            var msSubRoutes = routedata.Values["MS_SubRoutes"] as IEnumerable<IHttpRouteData>;
            if (msSubRoutes != null && msSubRoutes.Any())
            {
                var subRoute = msSubRoutes.FirstOrDefault();
                if (subRoute != null && subRoute.Values.ContainsKey(_routeId))
                {
                    return (string)subRoute.Values
                        .Where(x => x.Key.Equals(_routeId))
                        .Select(x => x.Value)
                        .Single();
                }
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

API action:

```
[Route("api/{tenantId}/Values/Get")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{

    _testService.DoDatabaseWork();

    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight: In ISiteContex is the logic that determines which connection string to use? (as stated in siteContext.SiteType). If so, could you help me out and add the implementation of that interface?

Comment: I've added some implementation code.  Let me know if that helps.  You can just as easily change to using headers instead of routes, or add additional connection string values in your web.config and refer to them using "name" instead of the formatted connection string that I copied out of web.config.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Looking at it now makes it seem so easy and simple. I totally missed the HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData (for me the headers of the request), so I couldn't figure out how to get the information from the request and put it in the correct variable(s)... And by doing so in the constructor. Well, another thing learned. Thank you for your perfect explanation and help

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a factory class for Dynamic picking of connection string. 
It is the responsibility of that class to give correct connectionString based on the certain Parameter.